# what is the purpose of backgroundWorker ? (can i get some sample code to understand ?)

Tags: c#

what is the purpose of backgroundWorker ? (can i get some sample code to understand ?)

thank's in advance

Comment: The basic idea is that you Seach around first, try something and then, if you get stuck, you ask a question here including some details.

Comment: I believe one of the points of StackOverflow is to have "the definitive google search answer". Even though the answer to this question could have been gotten by perusing the documentation, and the question could have been phrased with some more details,  I personally don't mind having such questions here, as you get answers like "I use it for the following..", which is more valuable than plain documentation.

Comment: alps, I agree, but the question would have been a lot better without the "give something to copy/paste" addition.

Comment: you dint get your answer?

Answer (score 22):

The background worker thread is there to help to offload long running function calls to the background so that the interface will not freeze.

Suppose you have something that takes 5 sec to compute when you click a button. During that time, the interface will appear 'frozen': you won't be able to interact with it.

If you used the background worker thread instead, the button event would setup the worker thread and return immediatly. That will allow the interface to keep accepting new events like other button clicks.

As far as code here are 2 examples:

Here the interface will freeze

```
protected void OnClick( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    CallLongRunningFunction(); // will take 5 seconds 
}
```

Here, it won't as the OnClick will return immediately and the long running function will
be executed in another thread.

```
protected void OnClick( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
     BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
     bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bg_DoWork);
     bg.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
     CallLongRunningFunction(); // will take 5 secs
}
```

The difference in behavior is because the call to the background worker thread will not execute in the same thread as the interface, freeing it to continue its normal work.

Comment: Closest to "what is the purpose"

Comment: When using a BackgroundWorker, make sure you give visual feedback that the button is pressed. This can be a simple disable/enable of the button itself and/or using the OnProgress event handler to show the progress of the background thread. Also be aware that your code needs to be thread safe (see http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/MultithreadingIntro10062005000439AM/MultithreadingIntro.aspx?ArticleID=920ecafc-e83b-4a9c-a64d-0b39ad885705).

Answer (score 3):

The *BackgroundWorker* is designed to let you run heavy or long operations on a seperate thread to that of the UI. If you were to run a lengthy process on the UI thread, your UI will most likely freeze until the process completes.

However the *BackgroundWorker* goes a step further by simplifying the threading process for you. If you were to create your own thread to run the heavy or lengthy process you would need to use delegates to access the UI thread to update a progress bar for example. With the *BackgroundWorker* you don't need any delegates because the *BackgroundWorker*'s **ProgressChanged** event already runs on the UI thread and you can add your UI updating code there.

To start the *BackgroundWorker* you need to call **RunWorkerAsync()**:

```
this.backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

To manually stop it call **CancelAsync()**...

```
this.backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
```

And then check the **CancellationPending** property from within the **DoWork** event as shown in the below example:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Example heavy operation
    for (int i = 0; i <= 999999; i++)
    {
        // Sleep for 10ms to simulate work
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);

        // Report the progress now
        this.backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i);

        // Cancel process if it was flagged to be stopped.
        if (this.backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote an article about how to use the *BackgroundWorker* on my blog. You can check it out here: [Using the BackgroundWorker Component in C#](http://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/09/using-the-backgroundworker-component-in-csharp/)

Answer (score 1):

It does work in the background by using [threads](http://dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker).

Answer (score 1):

To do work... in the background? :)

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx):

> The BackgroundWorker class allows you
>   to run an operation on a separate,
>   dedicated thread. Time-consuming
>   operations like downloads and database
>   transactions can cause your user
>   interface (UI) to seem as though it
>   has stopped responding while they are
>   running. When you want a responsive UI
>   and you are faced with long delays
>   associated with such operations, the
>   BackgroundWorker class provides a
>   convenient solution.

[The same page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) also has an extensive example. [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/LivMic/BGWorker07032007000515AM/BGWorker.aspx)'s another decent tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the BackgroundWorker class is to provide you an easy way to run operations on a separate thread.

It abstracts the thread creation and monitoring process, giving you an event driven API to report the progress of the operation ([ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx)) and determine when your operation is finished ([RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx))..

Is very useful when you need to run time-consuming tasks that can cause the UI to seem unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN documentation has a C# code example illustrating what the backgroundworker does and how to use it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx